# C# Best solution to get part of string between some text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like a

```
"[echo]\r\n[echo] Building VARIANT_SETTINGS 05...\r\n[echo] VARIANT_SETTINGS file 1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex successfully generated!\r\n"
```

How is it possible to get the `1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex`?

I tried to do this via Regex.Replace, but I don't understand well how it is happen. I tried

```
fileName = Regex.Replace(hexOutInfo, @"^.*VARIANT_SETTINGS file ([ ._0-9a-z-]+) successfully generated!.*$", "$1");
```

That returns to me the whole text.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

> An instance of the Match class is returned by the `Regex.Match` method and represents the first pattern match in a string. Subsequent matches are represented by Match objects returned by the `Match.NextMatch` method. In addition, a `MatchCollection` object that consists of zero, one, or more `Matc`h objects is returned by the `Regex.Matches` method.
>
> ...
>
> If a pattern match is successful, the `Value` property contains the matched substring, the `Index` property indicates the zero-based starting position of the matched substring in the input string, and the `Length` property indicates the length of matched substring in the input string.
>
> Because a single match can involve multiple capturing groups, `Match` has a `Groups` property that returns the `GroupCollection`. The `GroupCollection` has accessors that return each group. `Match` inherits from `Group` so the entire substring matched can be accessed directly. That is, the Match instance itself is equivalent to `Match.Groups[0]`  (`Match.Groups(0)` in Visual Basic).

I suggest modifying the regex to match only a part of the input and to avoid multi-line match issues.
The filename sub-expression needs to match both upper and lower case letters.

```
Regex mypattern = new Regex("VARIANT_SETTINGS file ([ ._0-9A-Za-z-]+) successfully generated!");
string filename = mypattern.Match(mytext).Groups[1].Value;
```

`filename` should now be `"1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex"`.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be:

```
        string hexOutInfo = "[echo]\r\n[echo] Building VARIANT_SETTINGS 05...\r\n[echo] VARIANT_SETTINGS file 1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex successfully generated!\r\n";

        string leftCrop = hexOutInfo.Replace("[echo]\r\n[echo] Building VARIANT_SETTINGS 05...\r\n[echo] VARIANT_SETTINGS file ", "");
        string hexFileName = leftCrop.Replace(" successfully generated!\r\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Regex.Match. Here is a quick and dirty solution

```
var str = "[echo]\r\n[echo] Building VARIANT_SETTINGS 05...\r\n" +
          "[echo] VARIANT_SETTINGS file 1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex " + 
          "successfully generated!\r\n"

var match = Regex.Match(str, @".*\sfile\s(?<name>.*\.hex)\s.*");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value);
```

outputs

```
1094_002-900208R7.0_05R01 02.hex
```

if you using it often you may want to compile and cache the regex. Also the pattern could be improved somewhat, but i will leave that for you to do.